# Remote port forwarding failed to listen on any port

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

For some reason, I am unable to forward ports.

```
# ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 crm-dev.sf
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 9000
```

ssh config:

```
Host crm-dev.sf
    Hostname ***
    User ***
    Port 10022
    ForwardAgent yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

I tried some different random ports and three different servers with the same result. My colleagues can connect to the servers without any problem, so I guess the problem has to be on my machine. I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.3.

When I use `netstat` or `lsof`, I don't see any processes listening on any ports I have tried on any machine.

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: The remote server might be configured [not to allow forwarding](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AllowTcpForwarding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out, that I had set `no-port-forwarding` option for my ssh key on the servers.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Accepting your own answer will mark this solved.  BTW, this answer got into the [Low Quality Posts review queue](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/835689) because of its brevity.  It might be helpful to other readers if you can expand the answer with any useful details.